# Is the server connected to localhost and is running on port 5432 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am working on an old rails app (version 2.3) and I'm unable to test my unit models because when I run `rake db:test:load` I receive this error message:

```
Is the server running on host "localhost" (10.0.1.245) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This is my database.yml file for test:

```
 test:
  db_host: localhost
  db_port: 5432
  db_name: app_test
  db_user: app_user
  db_pass: password
```

I've tried to trouble shoot using this resource and tried to modify the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf files:

```
 listen_address = "*"
```

[Common Problems for Postgresql](http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql/errors.html#cannot-connect-remote)

I've also consulted the Postgresql Documentation for the postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf file but I know that this could not be the problem. Those two files primarily deal with foreign entities such as virtual machines/ssh etc. This has to be a rails problem.

What I don't understand is where localhost (10.0.1.245) is coming from. In my /etc/hosts file, I have these entries.

```
  1 127.0.0.1 dev.app.net
  2 
  3 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
  4 ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  5 fe00::0 ip6-localnet
  6 ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
  7 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
  8 ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  9 ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Changing the database.yml file to refer to dev.app.net for db_host does nothing. Neither does adding localhost 10.0.1.245 accomplish anything. How do I fix this?

Comment: _localhost (10.0.1.245)_: indeed that's unusual and broken since `localhost` is reserved for loopback. You may add `127.0.0.1 localhost` in `/etc/hosts` in the hope that it will take precedence over the broken name resolution, wherever it comes from (bad DNS maybe?)

Comment: OS X? I've seen some bizarre and broken things with localhost resolution on OS X.